# How can I convert a UUID from binary format to string format in Lua?

Tags: string, lua, uuid

I have a UUID in binary format in my Lua program (just 16 bytes in string). I need to convert it to string format, for example `550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000`.

How can I convert it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string.format("%02x%02x%02x%02x-%02x%02x-%02x%02x-%02x%02x-%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x", string.byte(str,1,16))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a program to convert a 2 bytes string to its hex format:

```
local str = "\x55\x0e"
local result = string.format("%02x%02x", string.byte(str, 1, 2))
print(result)
```

Output: `550e`

`string.byte` gets the internal numeric representation of the characters, and then use `string.format` to get the hex format.

You can extend it to convert a UUID yourself.